# Fancybox preview in wrong spot on BigCommerce site

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, bigcommerce

I'm working on a BigCommerce site that I'm fairly new to. If you click on an image thumbnail, the full size image is off to right instead of centered. If I close the image and click the thumbnail again, the "full size" image gets smaller. It seems like the translate that's being applied is wrong, but I can't figure out what's going on.

I'm new to the site and to BigCommerce in general, and I could use some insight as to what might be happening.

https://www.peekaboopatternshop.com/stof-happy-floral-knit/

Answer (score 1):

The theme itself seems broken. You should probably contact your theme developer: https://themes.psdcenter.com/theme-demo/barcelona-premium-bigcommerce-theme/

Comment: Is there sometimes specific that makes you think the theme overall is broken, instead of just a fancybox issue?

Comment: Oh, I meant it is not an issue with your customization.